# Tengo que saber cuantas veces se repite un elemento

Tags: javascript

```js
function cuantosRepetidos(array, elemento) {
```

La función llamada `cuantosRepetidos` recibe como argumentos: un `Array` de `Array's` llamado `array` y un `string` llamado `elemento`

Cada *subarray* contiene `string's`.

Debe devolver la cantidad de veces que `elemento` se repite dentro de los subarrays. Por ejemplo, la llamada:

```js
cuantosRepetidos([['manzana', 'naranja'],['sandia', 'pera'],['uva', 'manzana']], 'manzana')
```

Debe retornar 2, ya que 'manzana' se repite 2 veces.
Nota: Podes usar for loops anidados.

```js
function cuantosRepetidos(array, elemento){
    var contador = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for(item of array[i]){
            if(item === elemento) {
                contador++;
            } // fin if
        } // fin for
    } // fin for
} // fin function
    return contador; // ???
} // ???

cuantosRepetidos([['manzana', 'naranja'],['sandia', 'pera'],['uva', 'manzana']], 'manzana');
```

Esto es lo que hice pero al pasarlo por un test me da error.

Comment: Tienes una llave `}` de más antes de `return contador;`

Comment: Ya se lo saque pero al correr el test me da el contador en 0, no calcula cuantos arrays estan repetidos

Answer (score 7):

Estás cometiendo el *pecado capital* de no indentar el código.

El código se indenta, no para ayudar a la computadora, que lo procesa como sea, siempre que la sintaxis sea válida.

El código se indenta para **ayudarte a ti mismo**, pues es mucho más fácil de entender, además de poder apreciar de manera mucho más rápida un error *tan básico* como el que estás cometiendo:

**Tu código tiene una llave de cierre de más.**

Al corregir ese *detalle*, además de indentarlo correctamente, obtenemos:

```js
function cuantosRepetidos(array, elemento) {
  var contador = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for(item of array[i]) {
      if(item === elemento) {
        contador++;
      }
    }
  }
  return contador;
}

console.log('Repetidos: ' + cuantosRepetidos([['manzana', 'naranja'],['sandia', 'pera'],['uva', 'manzana']], 'manzana'));
```

Como ves, he agregado una salida a la consola para ver directamente el resultado, que puedes ejecutar directament en el navegador (con el botón *ejecutar* de arriba).

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas **item** en el for...of, debes definirlo primero, sino puede dar error en alguna consola.

```
   function cuantosRepetidos(array, elemento) {
     var contador = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       for(let item of array[i]) {
        if(item === elemento) {
         contador++;
        }
      }
     }
     return contador;
   }

 console.log('Repetidos: ' + cuantosRepetidos([['manzana', 'naranja'],['sandia', 
  'pera'],['uva', 'manzana']], 'manzana'));
```